# New post at blog

Tags: blogs, posts

Assuming there is a blog which doesnt have RSS feed association and I am not registered to any notification regarding this blog  , I want to be able to "know" each time a new post is published on it.

Is there any way I can do that? I'm looking for a generic solution ...

Comment: Open browser, navigate to blog, check if there is a new post. Seriously, you need to be a bit more descriptive... do you want to do it programmatically? In what language? Interested in a specific blog platform?

Comment: I need it to be platform independent , preferably in PHP

Answer (score 2):

Pseudo cron script, run /1 * * * *

```
curl http://thatguysblog.html -> latest.blog;
grep latest.blog "posted at $1\n";
readf previous.time;
If (unixtime($1) > $previoustime) {
   send SMS me@myphone.com "OMG, a new blog post!!!";
}
printf $1 previous.time;
```